# Reindex programatically using recursion

Tags: reindex

Is there an issue in recursion when you are using singletons?

```
private function manageReindexing(){
        $stockIndex = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('cataloginventory_stock');
        if($stockIndex->getStatus() != "working"){
            $stockIndex->reindexAll();
            return;
        }
        else{
            Mage::log('still running',null,"log.log");
            sleep(60);
            $this->manageReindexing();
        }
    }
```

This method appears to run forever although `$stockIndex->getStatus()` has a status of `pending`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is that you are getting an outdeted version of `$stockIndex` object with a different status when using this approach.

Try with:

```
...
protected $_stockIndex = null;
...
private function manageReindexing() {
  if (is_null($this->_stockIndex)) {
    $this->_stockIndex = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('cataloginventory_stock');
  }

  if($this->_stockIndex->getStatus() != "working"){
    $this->_stockIndex->reindexAll();
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Mage::log('still running',null,"log.log");
    sleep(60);
    $this->manageReindexing();
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Of course I expect you to call this class as singleton.